# How to check conditional constraints added to the model?

Tags: gurobi, gurobipy

I want to know how I can check constraints like https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/py_model_agc_indicator.html in my model using something like `model.disply()` function. E.g. for the following dummy example:

```
import gurobipy as gp

model = gp.Model()

x = model.addVar(vtype=gp.GRB.BINARY, name="x")
y = model.addVar(vtype=gp.GRB.BINARY, name="y")
a = model.addVar(vtype=gp.GRB.BINARY, name="a")


z = model.addVar(vtype=gp.GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="z", ub=30)
model.addGenConstrAnd(a, [x, y], "andconstr")

model.update()

# constr1 = model.addConstr(z <= 20)
constr2 = model.addConstr((a == 0) >> (z <= 5))

model.setObjective(z+x+y+a, gp.GRB.MAXIMIZE)

model.update()
# Solve the model
model.optimize()
model.display()
```

calling `model.display()` will only show me the following:

```
Maximize
  x + y + a + z
Subject To
Bounds
  0 <= z <= 30
Binaries
  ['x', 'y', 'a']
```

and it dos not show anything regarding:

```
model.addGenConstrAnd(a, [x, y], "andconstr")
```

or:

```
constr2 = model.addConstr((a == 0) >> (z <= 5))
```

Is there a way to see such information in Gurobi `model.display()` or some similar function?

Comment: tried model.write('model.lp') or model.write('model.mps')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use model.write('filename.lp') or model.write('filename.mps'). AND constraint will appear in the section General constraints(lp) or GENCONS(mps).

```
Subject To
 GC1: a = 0 -> z <= 5
Bounds
 z <= 30
Binaries
 x y a
General Constraints
 andconstr: a = AND ( x , y )
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the same results without writing results into a file?

Comment: This I'd put to Gurobi community portal. They'd be best placed to respond or they can use your input as feature improvement in next version.